# Can I just use AjaxControlToolKit NoBot, instead of a Captcha?

Tags: asp.net, security, ajaxcontroltoolkit, captcha, bots

Is it still safe to just use [AjaxControlToolKit's NoBot](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/NoBot/NoBot.aspx) Control, instead of using a Captcha control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NoBot is check for

1. Posting back quickly
2. Posting back many times
3. Javascript on the browser is disabled.

What this mean, that when a crawler find the page and post back immediate, or did not support javascript then is not permit to post back. Now if the user did not support javascript, or if javascript throw an error for any reason, then is not working at all.

Is a very nice and good idea as alternative for the captcha for low traffic sites, that this mean for sites that you do not get so many spams, is not 100% effective but its work in most of the times. If a good spammer is attack you then can by pass this one, but if you do not have many attacks and you just like to avoid some low teck spammers, this can work.